# How to save a list of data frames with different number of rows into one file in R?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a list of data frames with different number of rows (over 1M rows in each) that I would like to save to a single file as they are **without appending them or saving to separate files.** So that they keep the structure of a list of data frames **as they have different information and data types.**

```
data2 <- list("inventory"=inventory,"Warehouse"=Warehouse,"Shop_inventory"=Shop,"Result"=Result)
```

It seems that it only possible through saving each data frame in a separate file:

```
write.table(data2[[1]],"./df1.csv",sep = ",") 
write.table(data2[[2]],"./df2.csv",sep = ",")
```

and etc.

But I can bet there should be alternatives.

It would be ideal if there is a way to save it as MS Access-friendly type of file. There is `mdb.get()` function in `Hmisc` package. I wonder if there something similar that can write files in such formats?

Comment: install.packages('XLConnect')

Comment: I believe Excel can't take more than 1M rows?

Comment: Then this isn't an R question. Your question is "What's better than Excel". Funny thing is, the answer is R.

Comment: This question is about exporting data into a file..I need to have all data frames in a single file. So that I can open it in Access or any other tool to work with data.

Comment: `write.table()` has an `append` option for writing multiple data sets to a single file.

Comment: Neal, that's the problem. I can't find a way of saving without having to merge or append them into single data frame prior to saving it. I just can't believe that there is no functionality in R to save a list of data frames as a list of data frames.

Comment: `install.packages("ImportExport")`. It seems to have a function (`access_export`) that does that but I haven't tested it.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a general approach

```
# a list of data.frames
df1 <- data.frame(x=1:3, y=letters[1:3])
df2 <- data.frame(x=11:13, y=letters[11:13])
x <- list(df1, df2)

# combine
y <- do.call(rbind, x)

# write to csv
write.csv(y, 'test.csv', row.names=FALSE)
```

This does assume that all the data.frame objects have the same column names.

Comment: Thanks, Robert! I edited the question, so that it states more clearly what the issue actually is - each data frame has different data that can't and shouldn't be appended.

Comment: This is why it so important to provide a reproducible example (and a clear question). You can save the list to a single file with `saveRDS`. but it is not clear what you have in mind with "Access friendly".

Comment: Robert, I meant that it saves a list of data frames in a single file in a format that is compatible with MS Access.

Comment: Sure, but if such a file format actually exists, what would it look like? If you cannot tell us that, it is hard to help

Comment: Well, that's why I'm actually asking this question as there is no information online.. I was very surprised to learn that it's not possible to write .mdb files in R, for instance.

Comment: Who says that you cannot write to mdb files in R? See package `RODBC`. You never asked that question.

Answer (score 1):

Using `iris` data set here and creating a sample dataframe `df`. Using `xlsx` package's `write.xlsx` function and argument `append=TRUE`. You can keep `row.names` and `col.names` equal to `FALSE` or `TRUE` according to your requirements. Keep the `file` argument same.

```
  library(xlsx)
  df <- data.frame(a=1:10,b=11:20,c=21:30)

  write.xlsx(iris$Species, file="filename.xlsx", sheetName="Data1",row.names=F, col.names=F)
  write.xlsx(iris$Sepal.Length, file="filename.xlsx", sheetName="Data2",row.names=F, col.names=F,append=TRUE)
  write.xlsx(iris$Petal.Length, file="filename.xlsx", sheetName="Data3",row.names=F, col.names=F, append=TRUE)
  write.xlsx(df, file="filename.xlsx", sheetName="Data4",row.names=F, col.names=T, append=TRUE)
```

The output will have four sheets with different data in each in a file called `filename.xlsx` created in the current working directory of R.

Comment: Thanks, Sowmya. But each data frame has over 1M rows in it, which is the problem. That's is why I mentioned Access, as the tool to work with files that have over 1M rows.

Comment: You need to first search for tools which can play with large files, and then shift to R to just export it into that format, as you have asked how to save them into one file without appending, i.e. excel sheets. Excel sheet has 1,048,576 rows. The other tools available would be Power Pivot add-in to handle billion rows. Then we can think of exporting your data frames.

Comment: Also, there is a software named Delimit.

Comment: Sowmya, that's exactly the reason why I mentioned Access, once again. That's the tool to play with large databases.

Comment: Actually,  Access cannot handle large databases. It has a file size limit of 2GB.